# How can I remove and add element on Array by index in RxJS way?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

So, I have a array of "events":

```js
let events = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
```

I can add(push):

```js
let add = function(number){
  events = events.concat([number]);
}
```

I can remove:

```js
let remove = function(){
  events = events.filter(event => {
  return event != 3;
})
}
```

My first question:
How can I remove and add a element by index in "RxJS" way?

```js
let removeByIndex = function(index){
  //remove by index
}

let addByIndex = function(index){
  //add by index
}
```

My second question:
I need "reinvent the wheel" for all basic methods of Array on RxJS from and of?

Comment: There's a *reason* those methods don't exist on Observables, and based on your question it's not clear why you're using Observables at all. One of the *main points* of doing so is avoiding the very side effects you're trying to re-implement.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm not thinking in the reactive way. Thank you so much.

Comment: Think of an Observable as a black-box stream of data. You can make a new Observable/stream with a modification from one that already exists, but you can't modify the original. For instance, consider having an Observer on keypress events. Now you say you want to delete the keypress at index 3? What does that even mean? You want to push a keypress event onto the Observable? How? You are correct that you're not thinking reactive: your questions have no meaning in that model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's your purpose? Your Observable is just a publisher which is listen somewhere in your application?

In this case, you can just have a method `publish` where push your new array:

```js
class EventStream {
    private numbers$: Subject<number[]> = new Subject();
    //or BehaviorSubject if you want a default value

    publish(arrayNumberToPublish: number[]): void {
        this.numbers$.next(arrayNumberToPublish);
    }

    listen(): Observable<number[]> {
        return this.numbers$;
    }
}
```

In your code you listen the stream: `new EventStream().listen().(...)`

The second possibility is you want keep the array. I use it when I want stub a CRUD API:

```js
class EventManager {
    private events: number[] = [];
    private events$: Subject<number[]> = new Subject();
    //or BehaviorSubject if you want a default value

    getAllEvents(): Observable<number[]> {
        return this.events$;
    }

    addEvent(index: number): void {
        this.events = this.events.concat(index);
        this.events$.next(this.events);
    }

    removeEvent(index: number): void {
        this.events = this.events.filter((event) => event !== index);
        this.events$.next(this.events);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I enjoyed that.

Comment: @JhonataRibeiro your welcome! If my answer help you, you can upvote and/or validate the answer to help other people which have the same question ;)